# Unable to increase the dynamic port range on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, performance, tcpip, netsh

I'm trying to "tune" the TCP/IP stack on some Windows Server 2008 machines by following the instructions here: http://www.outsystems.com/NetworkForums/ViewTopic.aspx?TopicId=6956&Topic=How-to-tune-the-TCP%2FIP-stack-for-high-volume-of-web-requests

One of the suggestions is to increase the dynamic port range and I've tried doing so but it fails:

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh int ipv4 set dynamicportrange tcp start=32767 num=65535
The parameter is incorrect.
```

My question is: which parameter is incorrect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to run:

`netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp start=32765 num=32765`

This would set your dynamic port range to start at port 32765 and go through port 65530 (32765 ports)

Comment: That did it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `netsh int ipv4 set dynamicportrange tcp start=32767 num=32768`